# How to import data from a text file into a specific MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, import

I am consolidating various lists (text files) and spreadsheets by putting all the information into a MySQL database. In many cases, I simply need to import the entire contents of a TXT file into a specific column in MySQL.

My project is basically a dictionary. For example, I have a table that is called allWords. This column contains every word that could appear. On my local hard drive, I have a text file with all of these words. How do I get all of those words into my table?

I realize that there are several workarounds (using Excel, for example) that I could employ, but I would like to do this the "right" way, since this is only the beginning of many similar tasks.

I have tried a number of queries, all along the lines of this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/home/mysite/tmp/phpb8Lp3L' REPLACE INTO TABLE  `words` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ';'
ENCLOSED BY  '"'
ESCAPED BY  '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY  '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 
LINES # 60780 rows affected.
```

Is there no way to import directly into a COLUMN (as opposed to into a TABLE)? Should I look into a script to help me do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

LOAD DATA is expecting the file to be in the format that is produced by SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE.

If you want to load the contents of a single file into a field, you'll either need to use copy/paste or a script.